# Get character from a string in Scala but keep the result as a string?

Tags: scala

Imagine that I wanted to take the characters from a string in Scala but have the toInt conversion to behave as it would on a string instead of as on a character.

To illustrate the following code behaves like so:

```
"0".toInt // results in 0
"000".charAt(0).toInt // results in 48
```

I'd like a version of the second line that would also result in 0. I have a solution like the following:

```
"000".charAt(0).toString.toInt // results in 0
```

But I wonder if there is a more direct or better way?

Comment: What's wrong with `"000".toInt`? And what do you mean by "keep the result as a string"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
"000".substring(0, 1).toInt
```

But I'm not sure it's more "direct" than `"000".charAt(0).toString.toInt`

Comment: Yeah, hard to define exactly what I was wondering. For what it is worth, I think this solution is better.

Comment: Feel free to accept/upvote it then, although I upvoted @Lee's answer which I found useful :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `asDigit`:

```
val i: Int = "000".charAt(0).asDigit
```

Comment: Great answer. Upvoted but I'm accepting Tzach Zohar's answer as the best answer. Reasoning for this in the end was that using .substring returns a string (as the awkward wording of the question asked for and this answer gets the desired result from a character.

Comment: Either answer could have been the best, really.